# Integral of the positive part of a function in terms of layer cake representation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Let $f$ and $g$ be Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Show that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (f(x) - g(x))^+ \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\{g(x) < t < f(x)\}|\, dt.$$

My attempt: Using the identity, $(f-g)^+ = \frac{1}{2}( |f-g| + (f-g) )$, if the following equality of sets
$$\{g(x) < t < f(x)\} = \{-\frac{1}{2}|f(x)-g(x)| < t < \frac{1}{2}(f(x)-g(x))\}$$
hold for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, I am able to directly apply the layer-cake representation. However, I am only able to show the equality of sets holds for all $t\geq0$. Are there any other ways I can solve this problem? Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) to
$$
 I = \iint_{\Bbb R^d \times \Bbb R} h(x, t) \, d(x, t)
$$
where the function $h: \Bbb R^d \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
 h(x, t) = \begin{cases}
 1 & \text{ if } g(x) < t < f(x) \,.\\
 0 & \text { otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
For $x \in \Bbb R^d$ is
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x, t) \, dt = (f(x)-g(x))^+ \, ,
$$
and for $t \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
 \int_{\Bbb R^d} h(x, t) \, dx = |\{g(x) < t < f(x)\}| \, ,
$$
so that both the left-hand side and the right-hand side of your equation are equal to the integral $I$.