# layer cake representation with $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Question:** Let $2 < q < \infty$ and suppose $g,w$ are real-valued measurable functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $w \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
> $$\int_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon |g(x)| > t\}} |w(x)|^2 \, dx \leq \frac{A^q}{t^q}\ \text{for any}\ t >0$$ Prove that there exists $C> 0$ independent of $g$ so that
> $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(x) w(x)|^2 \, dx \leq C A^2.$$

**My attempt:**
Consider
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(x)w(x)|^2 \, dx &= \int_{\{|g| \leq 1\}} |g|^2 |w|^2 \, dx + \int_{\{|g| > 1\}} |g|^2 |w|^2 \, dx \leq \Vert w \Vert_{2} + \int_{\{|g| > 1\}} |g|^2 |w|^2 \, dx
\end{align*}
However, I am not sure how to proceed using the layer-cake representation of the integral, despite having $\{|g|^2 > 1\} = \{|g| > 1\}$. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: It is really $CA^2$ and not $CA^q$? Can the constant $C$ depend on $w$ or not?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, it is $C A^2$. The constant $C$ can depend on $w$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly as in [Integral of the positive part of a function in terms of layer cake representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4736510/integral-of-the-positive-part-of-a-function-in-terms-of-layer-cake-representatio/4736521#4736521) one can apply Fubini's theorem to the function $h: \Bbb R^n \times [1, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
 h(x, t) = \begin{cases}
 w(x)^2 & \text{ if } 1 < t < g(x)^2 \,,\\
 0 & \text { otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
This gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\Bbb R^d} g(x)^2 w(x)^2 \, dx &= 
\int_{g(x)^2 \le 1} g(x)^2 w(x)^2 \, dx
 + \iint_{\Bbb R^d \times [1, \infty)} h(x, t) \, d(x, t) \\
&= \int_{g(x)^2 \le 1} g(x)^2 w(x)^2 \, dx + \int_1^\infty \left(\int_{g(x)^2 > t} w(x)^2 \, dx \right) dt \\
& \le \Vert w \Vert^2 + \int_1^\infty \frac{A^q}{t^{q/2}} \, dt\\
&= A^2 \left( \frac{\Vert w \Vert^2}{A^2} + A^{q-2}\int_{1}^\infty t^{-q/2} \, dt \right) \, .
\end{align}
$$
The integral $\int_{1}^\infty t^{-q/2} \, dt$ is convergent since $q > 2$, so that the second factor on the right is a finite value which does not depend on $g$.

Comment: Thank you so much. By any chance you have seen and attempted this analysis question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745287/integral-of-continuously-differentiable-functions-in-mathbbrn ?

Comment: I will look at it when I find the time, but I cannot promise anything.

Answer (score 0):

Could I check if there any gaps in my proof?

Consider
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(x)w(x)|^2 \, dx &= \int_{\{|g| \leq 1\}} |g|^2 |w|^2 \, dx + \int_{\{|g| > 1\}} |g|^2 |w|^2 \, dx \leq \Vert w \Vert_{2}^2 + \int_{\{|g| > 1\}} |g|^2 |w|^2 \, dx
\end{align*}

Let $\{|g| > 1\} = \bigsqcup_{n\geq0} E_n$ where $E_n := \{2^{n} < |g| \leq 2^{n+1}\}$ for each $n\geq0$. Then by the hypothesis
$$\int_{E_n} |g|^2 |w|^2 \ dx \leq (2^{n+1})^2 \int_{E_n} |w|^2 \, dx \leq A^2 2^{2n + 2 - nq} = 4 A^q 2^{n(2-q)}$$ where $2 - q < 0$ so
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{|g| > 1\}} |g|^2 |w|^2 \, dx &= \sum_{n\geq0} \int_{E_n}|g|^2 |w|^2 \, dx\\
&\leq 4 A^q \sum_{n\geq0} 2^{n(2-q)}\\
&= A^q \frac{4}{1 - 2^{2-q}}\\
&= C_2(A,q) A^2
\end{align*}
Writing $\Vert w \Vert_2^2 = C_1(w) A^2$ for some constant $C_1= C_1(w) >0$ then taking $C = C_1 + C_2$ the result follows.