# Integral of continuously differentiable functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> ** Question:** Let $f$ be continuously differentiable real valued function on an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n, n\geq 2$. Show that for any $x \in B$,
> $$\int_B |f(x) - f(z)|\, dz \leq \int_B \int_0^1 |\nabla f(tz + (1-t)x)| |x-z|\, dt \, dz.$$
> Hence, show that
>
> 1. There exists a constant $C$ depending only on $n$ so that for each $x \in B$, we have
>    $$\int_B |f(x) - f(z)|\, dz \leq C |B| \int_B \frac{|\nabla f(y)|}{|y-x|^{n-1}}\, dy$$ where $|B|$ denotes the volume of the ball.
> 2. For any $p, q \geq 1$ with $\frac{1}{q}> \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n}$, there is a constant $C$ depending on $n,p,q$ so that
>    $$\left( \int_B |f(x) - f_B|^q \, dx \right)^{1/q} \leq C \left( \int_B |\nabla f |^p \, dx \right)^{1/p}$$ where $f_B = \frac{1}{|B|} \int_B f(x) \,dx$.

**My attempt:** I am only able to prove via MVT that for any $x, z \in B$ we have $|f(x) - f(z)| \leq |\nabla f(tz + (1-t)x| |x-z|$ due to $B$ being convex set. So, taking integral
$$\int_B |f(x) - f(z)\, dz =\int_B \int_0^1 |f(x) - f(z)\, dz \leq \int_B \int_0^1|\nabla f(tz + (1-t)x| |x-z| \, dt \,d z.$$
For the first part, I believe $C$ is part of the bound of the derivative in some closed ball centered at $x$, whereas the exponent $n-1$ follows from the factor of $|B|$. However, I am unable to proceed from here.

Whereas for the second part, it looks like a Sobolev inequality possibily involving the maximal function, again I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Any hints are appreciated.